# When i used @scheduled, the chunk in Spring Batch is not working

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch, chunks

I'm currently creating a Spring Batch job that should repeat every 10 seconds using the @Scheduled annotation. The Spring Batch works when first start Project. However, when I write the code using chunk, it doesn't work.

Step() used chunk and Step2() used tasklet but Step() is not working but Step2() is working.. I don't know Why.

```
//BatchConfiguration.java

import com.education.education2.entity.user.UserEntity;
import com.education.education2.mapper.UserMapper;
import org.springframework.batch.core.Job;
import org.springframework.batch.core.Step;
import org.springframework.batch.core.StepContribution;
import org.springframework.batch.core.job.builder.JobBuilder;
import org.springframework.batch.core.repository.JobRepository;
import org.springframework.batch.core.scope.context.ChunkContext;
import org.springframework.batch.core.step.builder.StepBuilder;
import org.springframework.batch.item.Chunk;
import org.springframework.batch.item.ItemProcessor;
import org.springframework.batch.item.ItemWriter;
import org.springframework.batch.item.support.ListItemReader;
import org.springframework.batch.repeat.RepeatStatus;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager;

import java.time.LocalDateTime;

@Configuration
public class BatchConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    private UserMapper userMapper;

    @Bean
    public Job job(JobRepository jobRepository, Step step, Step step2){
        return new JobBuilder("job", jobRepository)
                .start(step)
                .next(step2)
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Step step(JobRepository jobRepository, PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager) {
        return new StepBuilder("step", jobRepository)
                .<UserEntity, UserEntity>chunk(2)
                .transactionManager(transactionManager)
                .reader(new ListItemReader<UserEntity>(userMapper.findUserAll()))
                .processor(new ItemProcessor<UserEntity, UserEntity>() {
                    @Override
                    public UserEntity process(UserEntity user) throws Exception {
                        System.out.printf("step1");
                        if (user.getIsDlt().equals("Y") && user.getUdtDtm().plusYears(1).compareTo(LocalDateTime.now()) < 0) {
                            System.out.printf("Delete User: " + user.getUsrId() + '\n');
                            return user;
                        }
                        return null;
                    }
                })
                .writer(new ItemWriter<UserEntity>() {
                    @Override
                    public void write(Chunk<? extends UserEntity> user) throws Exception {
                        System.out.printf("Successfully Delete Users: " + user + "\n");
                    }
                })
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Step step2(JobRepository jobRepository, PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager) {
        return new StepBuilder("step", jobRepository)
                .tasklet((StepContribution contribution, ChunkContext chunkContext) -> {
                    System.out.printf("hi hello" + '\n');
                    Thread.sleep(10);
                    System.out.printf("=======doooneeee======" + "\n");
                    return RepeatStatus.FINISHED;
                }, transactionManager)
                .build();
    }
}
```

```
//BatchScheduler.java

import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.batch.core.JobParameters;
import org.springframework.batch.core.JobParametersBuilder;
import org.springframework.batch.core.JobParametersInvalidException;
import org.springframework.batch.core.launch.JobLauncher;
import org.springframework.batch.core.repository.JobExecutionAlreadyRunningException;
import org.springframework.batch.core.repository.JobInstanceAlreadyCompleteException;
import org.springframework.batch.core.repository.JobRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.Scheduled;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager;

import java.util.Calendar;

@Slf4j
@Component
public class BatchScheduler {

    @Autowired
    private JobLauncher jobLauncher;

    @Autowired
    private BatchConfiguration batchConfiguration;
    private JobRepository jobRepository;

    private PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager;

    @Scheduled(cron = "0/10 * * * * ?")
    public void runJob() {
        try{
            JobParameters jobParameters = new JobParametersBuilder()
                .addDate("timestamp", Calendar.getInstance().getTime())
                .toJobParameters();
            System.out.printf(jobParameters.toString());
            jobLauncher.run(batchConfiguration.job(jobRepository, batchConfiguration.step(jobRepository, transactionManager), batchConfiguration.step2(jobRepository, transactionManager)), jobParameters);
        } catch(JobExecutionAlreadyRunningException | JobInstanceAlreadyCompleteException
                | JobParametersInvalidException | org.springframework.batch.core.repository.JobRestartException e) {
            log.error(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

**- Result**
[image]

```
step1Delete User: userid2
step1Delete User: userid3
Successfully Delete Users: [items=[UserEntity(usrNo=1, usrId=userid2, usrPw=user123, usrNm=username2, isDlt=Y, regNo=001, regDtm=2021-07-07T17:03:22.822812, udtNo=001, udtDtm=2021-07-07T17:03:22.822812), UserEntity(usrNo=2, usrId=userid3, usrPw=user123, usrNm=username3, isDlt=Y, regNo=001, regDtm=2021-07-07T17:03:22.822812, udtNo=001, udtDtm=2021-07-07T17:03:22.822812)], skips=[]]
step1Delete User: userid4
step1Delete User: userid5
Successfully Delete Users: [items=[UserEntity(usrNo=3, usrId=userid4, usrPw=user123, usrNm=username4, isDlt=Y, regNo=001, regDtm=2021-07-07T17:03:22.822812, udtNo=001, udtDtm=2021-07-07T17:03:22.822812), UserEntity(usrNo=4, usrId=userid5, usrPw=user123, usrNm=username5, isDlt=Y, regNo=001, regDtm=2021-07-07T17:03:22.822812, udtNo=001, udtDtm=2021-07-07T17:03:22.822812)], skips=[]]
step1Successfully Delete Users: [items=[], skips=[]]
2023-07-13T16:40:42.751+09:00  INFO 7256 --- [           main] o.s.batch.core.step.AbstractStep         : Step: [step] executed in 42ms
2023-07-13T16:40:42.771+09:00  INFO 7256 --- [           main] o.s.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler     : Duplicate step [step] detected in execution of job=[job]. If either step fails, both will be executed again on restart.
2023-07-13T16:40:42.772+09:00  INFO 7256 --- [           main] o.s.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler     : Executing step: [step]
hi hello
=======doooneeee======
2023-07-13T16:40:42.802+09:00  INFO 7256 --- [           main] o.s.batch.core.step.AbstractStep         : Step: [step] executed in 30ms
2023-07-13T16:40:42.807+09:00  INFO 7256 --- [           main] o.s.b.c.l.support.SimpleJobLauncher      : Job: [SimpleJob: [name=job]] completed with the following parameters: [{}] and the following status: [COMPLETED] in 110ms
{'timestamp':'{value=Thu Jul 13 16:40:50 KST 2023, type=class java.util.Date, identifying=true}'}2023-07-13T16:40:50.020+09:00  INFO 7256 --- [   scheduling-1] o.s.b.c.l.support.SimpleJobLauncher      : Job: [SimpleJob: [name=job]] launched with the following parameters: [{'timestamp':'{value=Thu Jul 13 16:40:50 KST 2023, type=class java.util.Date, identifying=true}'}]
2023-07-13T16:40:50.022+09:00  INFO 7256 --- [   scheduling-1] o.s.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler     : Executing step: [step]
2023-07-13T16:40:50.023+09:00  INFO 7256 --- [   scheduling-1] o.s.batch.core.step.AbstractStep         : Step: [step] executed in 1ms
2023-07-13T16:40:50.024+09:00  INFO 7256 --- [   scheduling-1] o.s.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler     : Duplicate step [step] detected in execution of job=[job]. If either step fails, both will be executed again on restart.
2023-07-13T16:40:50.025+09:00  INFO 7256 --- [   scheduling-1] o.s.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler     : Executing step: [step]
hi hello
=======doooneeee======
2023-07-13T16:40:50.051+09:00  INFO 7256 --- [   scheduling-1] o.s.batch.core.step.AbstractStep         : Step: [step] executed in 26ms
2023-07-13T16:40:50.052+09:00  INFO 7256 --- [   scheduling-1] o.s.b.c.l.support.SimpleJobLauncher      : Job: [SimpleJob: [name=job]] completed with the following parameters: [{'timestamp':'{value=Thu Jul 13 16:40:50 KST 2023, type=class java.util.Date, identifying=true}'}] and the following status: [COMPLETED] in 31ms
{'timestamp':'{value=Thu Jul 13 16:41:00 KST 2023, type=class java.util.Date, identifying=true}'}2023-07-13T16:41:00.008+09:00  INFO 7256 --- [   scheduling-1] o.s.b.c.l.support.SimpleJobLauncher      : Job: [SimpleJob: [name=job]] launched with the following parameters: [{'timestamp':'{value=Thu Jul 13 16:41:00 KST 2023, type=class java.util.Date, identifying=true}'}]
2023-07-13T16:41:00.010+09:00  INFO 7256 --- [   scheduling-1] o.s.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler     : Executing step: [step]
2023-07-13T16:41:00.013+09:00  INFO 7256 --- [   scheduling-1] o.s.batch.core.step.AbstractStep         : Step: [step] executed in 3ms
2023-07-13T16:41:00.015+09:00  INFO 7256 --- [   scheduling-1] o.s.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler     : Duplicate step [step] detected in execution of job=[job]. If either step fails, both will be executed again on restart.
2023-07-13T16:41:00.017+09:00  INFO 7256 --- [   scheduling-1] o.s.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler     : Executing step: [step]
hi hello
=======doooneeee======
2023-07-13T16:41:00.033+09:00  INFO 7256 --- [   scheduling-1] o.s.batch.core.step.AbstractStep         : Step: [step] executed in 16ms
2023-07-13T16:41:00.034+09:00  INFO 7256 --- [   scheduling-1] o.s.b.c.l.support.SimpleJobLauncher      : Job: [SimpleJob: [name=job]] completed with the following parameters: [{'timestamp':'{value=Thu Jul 13 16:41:00 KST 2023, type=class java.util.Date, identifying=true}'}] and the following status: [COMPLETED] in 24ms
{'timestamp':'{value=Thu Jul 13 16:41:10 KST 2023, type=class java.util.Date, identifying=true}'}2023-07-13T16:41:10.017+09:00  INFO 7256 --- [   scheduling-1] o.s.b.c.l.support.SimpleJobLauncher      : Job: [SimpleJob: [name=job]] launched with the following parameters: [{'timestamp':'{value=Thu Jul 13 16:41:10 KST 2023, type=class java.util.Date, identifying=true}'}]
2023-07-13T16:41:10.020+09:00  INFO 7256 --- [   scheduling-1] o.s.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler     : Executing step: [step]
2023-07-13T16:41:10.021+09:00  INFO 7256 --- [   scheduling-1] o.s.batch.core.step.AbstractStep         : Step: [step] executed in 
2023-07-13T16:41:10.022+09:00  INFO 7256 --- [   scheduling-1] o.s.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler     : Duplicate step [step] detected in execution of job=[job]. If either step fails, both will be executed again on restart.
2023-07-13T16:41:10.023+09:00  INFO 7256 --- [   scheduling-1] o.s.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler     : Executing step: [step]
```

Comment: Your `ListItemReader` should be an `@Bean` with either `@JobScope` or `@StepScope`. It will currently be created once and all users will be read but never again.

Comment: @M.Deinum
Thank you. I solved this problem with your answer.

Comment: Additional, unrelated, for performance reasons I would do the filter in a query and not in the processor. That will increase your performance, it saves you from retrieving data that doesn't need to be retrieved and mapped. Your solution will work but if the amount of users grows it will grind to a halt.